# Evaluating a real definite integral using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I've tried to solve the following integral using residue theorem. $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{cosx}{1+x^2}dx$$ 
Firstly, I set the contour as a counterclockwise semi-circle with radius R (R is sufficiently large so the pole z = i is in the contour) in upper half plane.
Then the contour integral can be divided in two parts: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{cosz}{1+z^2}dz$$ $$\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{C}\frac{cosz}{1+z^2}dz$$
By residue theorem, the sum of two integrals is $$2\pi{i}\lim_{z\to i}\ (z-i)\frac{cosz}{(z+i)(z-i)} = \pi{cosi} = {\frac{\pi(e^2+1)}{2e}}$$
Then the value of the real integral can be obtained by substracting complex integral part from the entire integral.
To evaluate the complex part, convert $z=Re^{i\theta}$. Then $dz=iRe^{i\theta}d{\theta}$
The given integral is converted to the following integral:
$$\lim_{R\to \infty}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{cos(Re^{i\theta})}{1+R^2e^{2i\theta}}iRe^{i\theta}d{\theta}$$
$$ = \lim_{R\to \infty}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{e^{iRe^{i\theta}}+e^{-iRe^{i\theta}}}{1+R^2e^{2i\theta}}\frac{iRe^{i\theta}d{\theta}}{2}$$
$$ = \lim_{R\to \infty}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{e^{R(icos{\theta}-sin{\theta})}+e^{-R(icos{\theta}-sin{\theta})}}{1+R^2e^{2i\theta}}\frac{iRe^{i\theta}d{\theta}}{2}$$ 
$\lvert {1+R^2e^{2i\theta}}\rvert$ is equal or larger than ${R^2-1}$ by triangle inequality and the absolute value of numerator is equal or smaller than R. Therefore the absolute value of the integral is equal or smaller than $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{R}{2(R^2-1)}d{\theta}$$ 
This integral goes to $0$ as R goes to infinity. Thus, I thought the value of the given real integral should be ${\frac{\pi(e^2+1)}{2e}}$.
However, the correct answer is $\frac{\pi}{e}$. What's wrong with my solution?

Comment: Why do you claim that “the absolute value of numerator is equal or smaller than $R$”?

Comment: the magnitue of e to the power of i is 1 and the range of theta is from 0 to pi, so e to the power of -Rsin(theta) is smaller than 1. Isn't it right?

Comment: What about the $e^{R(i\cos\theta-\sin\theta)}+e^{-R(i\cos\theta-\sin\theta)}$?

Comment: Yes you're right. On second thought, I realized that the second exponential term is not between 0 and 1 unlike the first one... Then is it impossible to make the complex term 0 using squeeze theorem or any other way?

Comment: In fact, it's *not* true that$$\lim_{R\to \infty}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(Re^{i\theta})}{1+R^2e^{2i\theta}}iRe^{i\theta}d{\theta}=0.$$

Comment: I wondered if there is a way solving the integral without converting trigonometric function to exponential form, but it seems taking the real part of $e^{i\theta}$ is the only way to calculate this integral... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$ f(z)=\frac {e^{iz}}{1+z^2}. $$
Then
$$ \int_{-R}^{R} \frac {e^{ix}}{1+x^2} \, dx + \int_{C_{_R}} f(z)\,dz = 2 \pi i B$$
where
$B$ is the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=i$ and $C_{_R}$ is the upper half of the circle $|z|=R, R>1$ from $z=R$ to $z=-R$.

Comment: The question was about why a certain method leads to a wrong value.